# Get url from image field

Tags: entities, users

For each user, I created a new field called `field_cover`, this field is an image.

I want to get the `field_cover` path, to use it into a `background-image` property.

I try this but it does not work.

```
<?php print render (file_create_url($user_profile['field_cover'])); ?>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you include more information? What theme are you using? Is this line inside a tpl.php file? Otherwise, what's the content of $user_profile? Where is it defined? Notice that `render` needs a renderable element, but the function `file_create_url` doesn't return one - it just returns a URL string.

Answer (score 0):

The function `file_create_url()` in D7 needs a uri (see this useful [article](https://www.jamestease.co.uk/blether/convert-public-uri-to-relative-path-in-drupal)). You can typically access the uri of a file this way:

`$user_object->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']`.

In your case, since $user_profile seems to be an array of fields, try:

`file_create_url($user_profile['field_cover'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri'])`.

This should return the full URL of the image.

Further information in your question may help me fine tune this answer.

Comment: I have an undefined index : und ....

Comment: You really need to add more information to your question if you want any meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [URL FORMATTER](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module

> This module add a url formatter for image field. Then you can output image url directly.

Once enabled, go to your user manage fields, and change the picture field formatter to url.

If you are using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), Views UI will give you an option to change the format to url in your field settings.